# Sql Count is returning all row values

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, count

I have two table users and messages. Messages have status type 1 = unread . I want to get users data and latest message and message time. and also count of messages where messages.status = 1

```
 SELECT users.id, users.name,users.gender,users.status,users.image,users.device_id,users.created_at,users.updated_at,
  MAX(messages.created_at) as message_at,
    messages.user_id, messages.body as message,
    (SELECT COUNT(messages.id) WHERE messages.status = 1 and messages.user_id = users.id) as unread
     from messages 
     JOIN users on users.id = messages.user_id  OR users.id = messages.to_id
     GROUP BY user_id 
     ORDER BY message_at DESC
```

Above queries works. But count of unread it returns wrong numbers.

**Edits**

- I changed This query many problems solves like duplication. But still message count is wrong. I don't know. When All the messages.status != 1 its returns 0 as unread. But When there is one and more messages.status = 1 its shows wrong number :(

Here is updated query.

```
     SELECT  users.*,messages.body as message,messages.created_at as message_at,messages.type as message_type,
    (SELECT  COUNT(messages.id) WHERE (messages.status = 1 and users.id = messages.user_id) ) as unread
     from users 
     JOIN (
     SELECT  messages.*
            FROM messages
             ORDER BY messages.created_at DESC
     ) 
     messages on users.id = messages.user_id  OR users.id = messages.to_id
      GROUP BY users.id 
      ORDER BY message_at DESC
```

**Edits 2.**

I have two table.
1 - users

[image]

2 - messages [user_id = sender id & to_id = receiver id]

[image]

Desired Result.
I want to query all users. with latest message from messages ( for this I have to query all messages with user_id=id or to_id=id). Also with count on unread ( for this messages.status=1) messages.

Comment: What's your use case here? Are you hoping to present the person using your app with "number of messages you have written that are not read by other people" or is it "number of messages other people have written to you, that are not read by you"?

Comment: I want number of messages where messages.user_id and messages.status = 1. So My use case is simple just like whatsapp I want count on unread messages from incoming messages.

Comment: *I want number of messages where messages.user_id and messages.status = 1* - But do you though, because your messages table has a "to_id" which kind of implies that the user_id is the user that *wrote* the message, not who they wrote it *to*, and you're then saying that you want to show the person who *received* the message how messages they have received and not read. I think you need to be more clear about the design of your messages table; should `user_id` be called `author_id`? Seems like you should be querying on `to_id` only. If you want author and recipient *join users in twice*

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas I added my data base informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions like `MAX()`, `FIRST_VALUE()` and `SUM()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*,
       MAX(m.created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY u.id) AS message_at,
       FIRST_VALUE(m.body) OVER (PARTITION BY u.id ORDER BY m.created_at DESC) AS message,
       SUM(m.status IS 1) OVER (PARTITION BY u.id) AS unread
FROM users u LEFT JOIN messages m
ON u.id IN (m.user_id, m.to_id)
```

This returns the number of messages with `status = 1` of each user as a sender or receiver.

If you want only the number of messages that the user sent:

```
SUM(m.status IS 1 AND m.user_id IS u.id ) OVER (PARTITION BY u.id) AS unread
```

or the number of messages that the user received:

```
SUM(m.status IS 1 AND m.to_id IS u.id ) OVER (PARTITION BY u.id) AS unread
```

Comment: It's shows me one record only if I run on tableplus. But for the app it's shows error. like ``` misuse of aggregate: MAX() in "SELECT  u.*,
```

Comment: @VimalMistry I missed the OVER clause for MAX() window function. I edited.

Comment: Plz. Note I am using sqlite. If this cause the problem :)

Comment: @VimalMistry this code runs in SQLite version 3.25.0+

Comment: Perfect. Working as I excepted :). Thank you very much. Just added order by message_at :)

Comment: I am getting "Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(near "(": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):" on real device. Not a problem with Emulator. Anybody knows why?

Comment: @VimalMistry probably the version of SQLite in the device is prior to 3.25.0+

Comment: Sqlite version only available after android R(11). It is problematic. What should I change in query to support Atleast Sqlflite 3.9

Comment: @VimalMistry Try this: `SELECT u.*, MAX(m.created_at) AS message_at, m.body AS message, SUM(m.status IS 1) AS unread FROM users u LEFT JOIN messages m ON u.id IN (m.user_id, m.to_id) GROUP BY u.id` but you should know that window functions provide far better performance.

Answer (score 2):

I think It's because of OR operator .In this query you need exactly " JOIN on users.id = messages.user_id", but if You use OR operator this condition will has wrong numbers. I don't find out column "message.to_id". It works without OR:

```
 SELECT users.id, 
    users.name,users.gender,users.status,users.image,users.device_id,
 users.created_at, 
 users.updated_at,
 MAX(messages.created_at) as message_at,
messages.user_id, messages.body as message,
(SELECT COUNT(messages.id) WHERE messages.status = 1 and messages.user_id = 
  users.id) as unread
 from messages 
 JOIN users on users.id = messages.user_id  
 GROUP BY user_id 
 ORDER BY message_at DESC
```